# Expansion with *.txt in the shell doesn't work if no .txt file exists

Tags: command-line, bash

I was playing around with expansion, and I noticed a peculiar behavior. I tried doing:

```
echo ./*.txt
```

And I didn't have any .txt file in my current directory. The output I got was:

```
./*.txt
```

I'm just curious: Why did I get this? I was expecting to not get any output.

PS: When I did have a `.txt` file, the expansion was correctly interpreted. In other words, say I had a file, `smthn.txt`, the echo actually echoed `current_directory/smthn.txt`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Adapting from the bash shell man page,

> bash  scans each  word  for the characters *, ?, and [.  If one of
>   these characters appears, then the word is regarded as a pattern, and
>   replaced  with  an alphabetically  sorted list of filenames matching
>   the pattern.  If no matching  filenames  are  found,  and  the shell 
>   option  nullglob is not enabled, the word is left unchanged.  If the
>   nullglob option is set, and no  matches  are  found,  the  word  is
>   removed.

In this case I presume nullglob is not enabled, so the word is left unchanged - hence the output you see.

Comment: You can change the behaviour as follows: `shopt -s nullglob` will yield empty strings for unmatched patterns and `shopt -u nullglob` (standard setting) will yield the pattern itself.

Answer (score 14):

> I was expecting to not get any output.

If [`nullglob`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#nullglob) were the default, many commands would behave quite unexpectedly, because it is (perhaps unfortunately) common that commands treat the case of *zero* filename arguments in a qualitatively different way than the case of *one or more* filename arguments.

Suppose you've enabled `nullglob` (`shopt -s nullglob`) and you're in a directory where no files match `*.txt`. Then `*.txt` will indeed expand to nothing--not an empty field, but no fields at all--as you expected. But that would have these results:

- `ls *.txt` would list *all* the files in the current directory (except hidden files), because that's what `ls` does when you don't pass it any filename arguments.
- `cat *.txt` would read from [standard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_(stdin)), because when `cat` has no filename arguments, it's as if you ran `cat -`. If running interactively, it sits around waiting for input. Many commands behave this way.
- `cp *.txt dest/` would fail with the error `cp: missing destination file operand after 'dest/'`. This isn't a disaster, but it's confusing and quite different from the silent success that is probably desired.
- `file *.txt`, and various other programs with no *special behavior* for the case of zero filename arguments, would still fail with an error or usage message when none are passed.
- Even cases that intuitively feel like they should work often wouldn't. `printf 'Got file: "%s"\n' *.txt` would print `Got file: ""` instead of nothing.
- Accidental failure to quote occurrences of `*`, `?`, and `[` that *aren't* intended to be expanded by the shell would more often produce obviously wrong results, but in ways that might be difficult to figure out. For example, if no filenames in the current directory started with `gedit`, then `apt list gedit*` (where `apt list 'gedit*'` was intended) would become just `apt list` and list *all* available packages.

So it's good that you don't get this behavior without requesting it. Probably the most common practical situation that is actually simplified by `nullglob` is `for f in *.txt`. See also [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204803/why-is-nullglob-not-default) (which [Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1161188/22949) linked to).

The harder question to answer is why [`failglob`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#failglob)--where it's an expansion error to have a glob that doesn't match any files--isn't the default in bash. I believe [Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1161188/22949) captures the reason for this even without addressing it directly. Retaining unexpanding globs without producing an expansion error is (perhaps unfortunately) the standardized behavior, and it is also traditional, and thus expected, behavior. Although bash doesn't attempt to be fully POSIX-compliant unless it is invoked with the name `sh` or passed the `--posix` option, many of its design choices even when not in POSIX mode follow POSIX directly. They had to pick some behavior, and there are downsides associated with going against users' expectations.

---

I think this is the least historically influential aspect of the matter so I've saved it for last... but it is worth mentioning that there's something a bit conceptually odd about `nullglob` behavior.

`nullglob` seems elegant at first because, *syntactically*, it treats the case of *zero matching files* no differently from the case of one, two, or any other number. The commands we run, which globs expand into arguments for, *don't* tend to treat them the same, as detailed above. But syntactically this at least feels right, which I think is the motivation for your question.

And yet, there is another, more subtle inconsistency that `nullglob` doesn't address--that it actually amplifies. The case of *zero globbing characters* ("wildcards") is treated profoundly differently from that of one, or two, or any other number. For example, with `shopt -s nullglob`, if `ab?d?f` doesn't match any files, it is removed; if `ab?d` doesn't match any files, it is removed; but if `ab` doesn't match any files (i.e., if there is no file whose name is exactly `ab`) it is still not removed. Of course, it would be a disaster if it were removed, because it might not be intended to refer to an existing file in the current directory at all; it might not even refer to a file. But this still eliminates any hope for total consistency.

The three behaviors bash provides--the default of treating globs that don't match any files as though they weren't globs and passing them unexpanded, the behavior you expected of treating them (if you'll pardon this odd turn of phrase) as signifying all zero of the files that do match (`nullglob`), and the safe behavior of considering them errors (`failglob`)--all represent different approaches to the ambiguity inherent in the shell not being able to know if any particular word is intended to be a filename. The shell performs its expansions without knowledge of how the particular commands you call with it will treat their arguments.

This is one of many instances of [*separation of concerns*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). In systems whose design follows the Unix philosophy, each part is intended to [do one thing and do it well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy#Do_One_Thing_and_Do_It_Well). The shell processes text into commands and arguments and invokes those commands, most of which are external to the shell itself. This tends to be a lot nicer and more versatile than systems where the external commands are *themselves* responsible for performing those transformations (as with the traditional command processors in DOS and Windows). But it has its occasional downsides.

Comment: Apparently, bash-4.3.39(2) doesn't have `failglob`. So it can't the default because it hasn't always been supported.

Answer (score 6):

The main reason is because this is standard behavior specified by [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) - the standard which covers shell command language and among other things pattern matching ( shells such as `bash`, `dash` shell - Ubuntu's default `/bin/sh`, and `ksh` follow this standard ). From section [2.13.3 Patterns Used for Filename Expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13_03):

> If the pattern does not match any existing filenames or pathnames, the pattern string shall be left unchanged.

This of course has a side effect - matching filename that may be literally `*.txt`. The `nullglob` option in `bash` and `zsh` can help: if that option is enabled via `shopt -s nullglob` (and it is not enabled by default which applies to this question), then globstar will be expanded to empty string when no matching filenames found. `ksh93` has its own advanced pattern matching mechanism which achieves the same effect `~(N)*.txt`

See also [Why is nullglob not default?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/204944/85039)