# Use the '*' in shell script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, mv

I am trying to run a command example:

```
sudo mv /home/vaishnavi/Downloads/*.ttc /home/vaishnavi/Downloads/*.ttf /usr/local/share/fonts/ms_fonts/
```

It works fine in the terminal, but when I try to add this in a shell script (`.sh`) I get an error saying:

```
mv: cannot stat '/home/vaishnavi/Downloads/*.ttf': No such file or directory
```

Simply, I want to move all the files of `.ttf` and `.ttc` type to `/usr/local/share/fonts/ms_fonts/`, in this case. Frankly speaking, I am not so expert in shell scripts. Please explain to me what wrong I did and also an alternative to achieve my expected results.

My sample script:

```
sudo mv /home/vaishnavi/Downloads/*.ttc /home/vaishnavi/Downloads/*.ttf /usr/local/share/fonts/ms_fonts/  
...

exit 0
```

Comment: Can you post the script you are writing? Or at least the lines around the failing command

Comment: Aren’t you trying to move the files using the script _after_ you moved them all manually?

Comment: @Melebius I actually need the script to move each time after downloading something, it's not a one-time process. Whenever I download many `.png`s for example, I want to move them using the script.

Comment: Not sure, but might be duplicate of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161180/expansion-with-txt-in-the-shell-doesnt-work-if-no-txt-file-exists/1161188) or [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164497/mv-cannot-stat-with/271168)? See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204803/why-is-nullglob-not-default

Comment: This might help: https://askubuntu.com/q/1201366/968501

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll get this error if there are no *.ttf files there. By default, if no files match a glob pattern, then the pattern itself remains in the command. Turn this off with the bash `nullglob` shell option

To be a bit safer, verify there are actually some files to move:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
...
shopt -s nullglob
# store files in an array
files=( /home/vaishnavi/Downloads/*.{ttc,ttf} )
# and if the array is not empty, move the files.
if (( ${#files[@]} > 0 )); then
    sudo mv -t /usr/local/share/fonts/ms_fonts/ "${files[@]}" 
fi
```